# TypeError: 'Tk' object is not callable Why am i Getting this error message

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
window = tk.Tk()
# Size of Canvas

window_height = 400
window_width = 600
window_colour = "red"
thickness = 0


# Creating the Canvas

window = window(bg=window_colour, height = window_height, \
            width = window_width, highlightthickness = thickness)

# Variables of the Pen

p1_x = window_width/2
p1_y = window_height

p1_colour = "green"
line_width = 5
line_length = 5

# Player Controls, Up, Down, Left, Right and Clear the screen

def p1_move_N(event):
    global p1_y
    window.create_line(p1_x, p1_y, p1_x, (p1_y-line_length), 
    width=line_width,fill=p1_colour)
    p1_y = p1_y - line_length
p1_move_N()

def p1_move_S(event):
    global p1_y
    window.create_line(p1_x, p1_y, p1_x, (p1_y+line_length),width=line_width,fill=p1_colour)
    p1_y = p1_y + line_length
p1_move_S()

def p1_move_W(event):
    global p1_x
    window.create_line(p1_x, p1_y, (p1_x-line_length),p1_y, width=line_width,fill=p1_colour)
    p1_x = p1_x - line_length
p1_move_W()

def p1_move_E(event):
    global p1_x
    window.create_line(p1_x,p1_y, (p1_x+line_length), p1_y, width=line_width,fill=p1_colour)
    p1_x = p1_x + line_length
p1_move_E()
def erase_all(event):
    canvas.delete(ALL)
erase_all()    

# Keyboard Controls

window.bind("<Up>", p1_move_N)
window.bind("<Down>", p1_move_S)
window.bind("<Right>", p1_move_E)
window.bind("<Left>", p1_move_W)
```

Please can someone help me with this it's for my school work and also I am on a Macbook Pro
I am new to python and would really appreciate some help. When I run it it says TypeError: 'Tk' object is not callable but when I visit other websites and this one I get different ways of doing it and none of them seem to work so I thought posting my code would help a lot.

Comment: Where you have written `window = window(bg=window_colour, height = window_height, width = window_width, highlightthickness = thickness)`, what do you expect this to do?

Comment: "when I visit other websites and this one I get different ways of doing it" What is the *it* you are trying to do, specifically? Could you show some complete examples of what you tried based on "other websites" (include links to them) and explain how they failed?

Answer (score 0):

You used same variable `window` for the root window (`window = tk.Tk()`) and the *canvas* (`window = window(...)`, but it should be `canvas = tk.Canvas(...)`).

Below is a modified code with fixing the name conflict:

```py
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()

# Size of Canvas
window_height = 400
window_width = 600
window_colour = "red"
thickness = 0

# Creating the Canvas
canvas = tk.Canvas(bg=window_colour, height = window_height,
                   width = window_width, highlightthickness = thickness)
canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=1)

# Variables of the Pen

p1_x = window_width/2
p1_y = window_height

p1_colour = "green"
line_width = 5
line_length = 5

# Player Controls, Up, Down, Left, Right and Clear the screen

def p1_move_N(event=None):
    global p1_y
    canvas.create_line(p1_x, p1_y, p1_x, (p1_y-line_length), 
    width=line_width,fill=p1_colour)
    p1_y = p1_y - line_length
#p1_move_N()

def p1_move_S(event=None):
    global p1_y
    canvas.create_line(p1_x, p1_y, p1_x, (p1_y+line_length),width=line_width,fill=p1_colour)
    p1_y = p1_y + line_length
#p1_move_S()

def p1_move_W(event=None):
    global p1_x
    canvas.create_line(p1_x, p1_y, (p1_x-line_length),p1_y, width=line_width,fill=p1_colour)
    p1_x = p1_x - line_length
#p1_move_W()

def p1_move_E(event=None):
    global p1_x
    print('move E')
    canvas.create_line(p1_x,p1_y, (p1_x+line_length), p1_y, width=line_width,fill=p1_colour)
    p1_x = p1_x + line_length
#p1_move_E()

def erase_all(event=None):
    canvas.delete(ALL)
#erase_all()    

# Keyboard Controls

canvas.bind("<Up>", p1_move_N)
canvas.bind("<Down>", p1_move_S)
canvas.bind("<Right>", p1_move_E)
canvas.bind("<Left>", p1_move_W)
# need to make canvas focused, otherwise keyboard events will not be received
canvas.focus_set()

window.mainloop()
```

---

Note: it is bad practice to import `tkinter` module like below:

```py
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
```

It is recommended to use `import tkinter as tk`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help it works great! I have been trying for weeks Thank you!